# Creating tables in pgadmin sql editor?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, pgadmin

I am failing in creating tables via the PGadmin III SQL editor - even if the syntax is generated by the frontend:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable
(
   id integer, 
   "name" character varying(100)
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
)
;
```

Error message is in german, but basically says that there's supposed to be a syntax error..

```
FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »integer«
ZEILE 3:    id integer, 
                ^

********** Fehler **********
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Works fine, no problem at all. Just copy-paste the above example and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me.

However I see the error is indicated at line 11. Is it possible the previous statement was not properly terminated and the interpreter chooses this point to give up?

Comment: That was a copy and paste fault ;-)

But you're both right, it works after copying it in a new window. 
I tried to analyze the query before (and the editor is still throwing that same syntax error when analyzing). Probably it somehow got messed up in some way after analyzing.